# Do Asp.Net handlers pass data back to HttpResponse?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httphandler

Q1:

A) I assume web form passes rendered html to HttpResponse object, and in turn  HttpResponse object passes these rendered data back to IIS?

B) I also assume that regardless of which Asp.Net http handler processes the request, all Http handlers eventually pass data back to HttpResponse?

Q2 - When request is received by Asp.Net application, when in the life cycle of that request do HttpResponse and HttpRequest objects become available?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Q1.A: Yes
- Q1.B: Yes
- Q2: Immediately, they are available everywhere in the life cycle.